# How do I resolve "Graphics Device initialization failed for : es2, sw" when running on WSL?

Tags: java, javafx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to setup [**okta-aws-cli-assume-role**](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aws-cli-assume-role), but I have a Windows machine (please don't shoot me!). I think my problem is there is some graphical components, and when I run with a Ubuntu WSL, it can't find the appropriate device.

The full error is:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some may suggest you a workaround for this problem, I suggest you to take a look at [aws-sts](https://github.com/meetearnest/aws-sts) docker solution: it uses headless browser under the hood, so there won't be any problems related to the graphics and it is more or less platform independent.

I was exactly in the same situation using WSL, so what I did:

- created `config.json` as described in the Readme
- ReadMe suggests to create a Dockerfile, but actually I never had to use it just passing the config parameters to the basic docker image like in [the template file](https://github.com/meetearnest/aws-sts/blob/master/example/aws-token)

As the result, aws token is generated inside the docker container and put into mounted `$HOME/.aws` folder, so you can easily call `awscli` from WLS.

[Here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly) is how to make docker working properly with WLS (in short, client in WLS, server installed on Windows with exposed daemon).

One more hint: use `--profile=default` when generating token, so you don't have to specify it every time you use `awscli`.

Comment: What do I do for `ORG`?

Comment: `ORG` is used in the names of custom docker images. If you don't create a separate docker image for your organization, use earnest/aws-sts (https://hub.docker.com/r/earnest/aws-sts/).

Comment: @GoodDoc, I tried to follow the instructions, but I get `Error: Cannot find module '../cfg/config'` even though I have the `config.json` in my current path

Comment: Create a folder like `cfg`, put your `config.json` there and add one more bind mounting when starting container like `-v /host/path/to/cfg:/usr/src/app/cfg`. The point here is that the configuration should be placed inside the container, the approach creating a docker image suggests that it will be placed inside on build (https://github.com/meetearnest/aws-sts/blob/432ade3513b771db75cc405baf1e2400d97cb93c/Dockerfile#L26), but bind mounting lets us overcome this.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the bind mounting? When I run `aws-token`, it runs `docker run` with some parameters

Comment: Replace the default contents in `aws-token` with `docker run -it --rm -v $HOME/.aws/:/root/.aws/ -v /host/path/to/cfg:/usr/src/app/cfg earnest/aws-sts "$@"` with the correct path to your `cfg` directory and let me know what happens when you run it.

Comment: Super strange issue now. I got to some debugging and I can get Electron to load the Okta signin screen, and even submit credentials. But it says "signin failed," even though the credentials are valid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199025/discussion-between-gooddok-and-shamoon).